# Slavnov-Taylor identities and the Ward identity

Tags: quantum-field-theory, yang-mills, ward-identity

Suppose we have a vertex $\Gamma$ that satisfies the Slavnov-Taylor identity:

$$
p^{\mu} q^{v} \Delta_{\sigma \lambda}^{\mathrm{tr}}(r) \Gamma_{\mu \nu \lambda}(p, q, r) =\frac{1}{\widetilde{Z}\left(p^{2}\right)}\left[\delta_{\sigma \lambda}-\frac{r^{\sigma} r^{\lambda}}{r^{2}}\right] q^{\mu} \widetilde{\Gamma}_{\lambda \mu}(r, p ; q),
$$
where the underlying theory is non-Abelian but not necessarily Yang-Mills.
If this is satisfied, does this imply that any scattering amplitude built from this vertex will satisfy the Ward identity? E.g.
$$
k_\mu \mathcal{M}^\mu = 0,
$$
where $\mathcal{M}^\mu$ is an on-shell amplitude built only out of propagators, and vertices $\Gamma$.

To give a specific example, consider topologically massive gauge theory, where the vertices are given by

$$
\Gamma_{\mu \nu \lambda}(p, q, r)=m \varepsilon_{\mu \nu \lambda}+\eta_{\mu v}(p-q)_{\lambda}+\eta_{\nu \lambda}(q-r)_{\mu}+\eta_{\lambda \mu}(r-p)_{\nu},~~~~~\widetilde{\Gamma}_{\lambda \mu}(r, p ; q) = \eta_{\lambda \mu}.
$$
and
$$
\Delta_{\mu\nu}^{\mathrm{tr}}(r) = \frac{1}{2p^{2}\left(p^{2}+m^{2}\right)}\left(\eta_{\mu\nu}-\frac{p_{\mu} p_{v}}{p^{2}}-m \varepsilon_{\mu v \lambda} \frac{p^{\lambda}}{p}\right).
$$

Comment: What does _not necessarily Yang-Mills_ mean? A combination of Yang-Mills and Chern-Simons?

Comment: This is what I had in mind, Yes. Topologically massive Yang-Mills for example.

Comment: Assuming the "vertex" is an 1PI correlator (?), and the ST identities hold for all such, the answer is yes. The point is that the Zinn-Justin equation for the 1PI functional (equivalent to the ST identities) implies a similar equation for the S-matrix generating functional that produces the  Ward identities. This is true rather generally and I wrote about it in 2019 in the context of L-infinity algebras in QFT but I don't specialise to YM-type theories

Comment: you should define all the symbols here. What is $\Gamma,\tilde \Gamma,\Delta^\text{tr},\tilde Z$, etc.? (definition as in equations, please, not just the name of these objects)

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform I've updated the question a bit to include some specifics.

Comment: Thanks @alexarvanitakis, I'll take a look at your paper.

Comment: @Akoben Sorry, maybe I did not explain myself properly. I don't want the value of $\Gamma$ in a specific theory, I want its general definition. Is this an amputated correlation function? Something like $\Gamma^{\mu\nu\lambda}=\langle J^\mu J^\nu J^\lambda\rangle$? I want the *definition* of these objects, not their value. Thanks!

Comment: Ahh! I see. Yes, these are amputated correlation functions if you like, although really I just want to build the S-matrix out of them and I am asking about a purely on-shell statement.

Comment: If you don't @ me I don't get notified. So, $\Gamma$ is the amputated three point function of three currents. What is $\tilde \Gamma,\Delta^\text{tr},\tilde Z$, etc.?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform right you are! $\tilde{\Gamma}$ is the FP ghost vertex, $\Delta^{tr}$ the transverse part of the gluon propagator and $\tilde{Z}$ some renormalisation constant.